# deleting from sql database with php function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two php functions. deletebooking works fine but the other does not. I'm not sure if it would be better to combine them or not.

I run this which calls the functions. However I cannot get it too run the deletebookingIf function. can anyone see any errors?

```
$idnumber = $_GET['del'];

 if($_GET['del']) {
   deletebookingIf($idnumber);
   deletebooking($idnumber);
 }

function deletebooking($orderID) {    
    $sql = "DELETE FROM bs_reservations 
             WHERE id = '".$orderID."'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("oopsy, error when tryin to delete events 2");
}

function deletebookingIf($orderID) {        
    $sql = "SELECT DURATION 
              FROM bs_reservations 
             WHERE id = '".$orderID."'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("oopsy, error when tryin to delete events 2");

    if ($result != "One Day Rental") {
      $orderID2 = $orderID - 1;
      $qq = "DELETE FROM bs_reservations 
              WHERE id = '".$orderID2."'";
      $result = mysql_query($qq) or die("oopsy, error when tryin to delete events 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know where to begin. Possibly with: SQL injection alarm!

Comment: im not too worried about it, its a small site. Plus hahah I have no idea how to get around it, i only know basic sql.

Comment: @Simon o_O [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Maaybe if you send us the URL you'll see how much you lose when somebody goes crazy with your sql injection issue... you have to fix it!

Comment: I want to fix it, its very complex though.

Comment: just use mysql_real_escape_string as sdleihssirhc suggested above, it's the least you can do and also safe enough to begin with.

Comment: i dont even know how i would incorporate it, i read through the documentation and didnt understand exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
if ($result != "One Day Rental") {
```

You should have:

```
if ($result) {
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($data['duration'] != 'One Day Rental') {
    // rest of the code
```

$result contains a set of rows, not the contents of a field. If that id isn't a primary key, you should also use LIMIT 1 in your query to make sure you return only one line. You should also use mysql_num_rows($result) to make sure you do have an entry for that id.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over `$result` from the select query with a `mysql_fetch_assoc` (or similar) function to grab the rows from your query. Then, for each matching row, you can either add that rows ID to a local array of ID's and then run the `delete` query with an `in` clause passing the id's, or run the `delete` query through each iteration of the `mysql_fetch_assoc` block. Check http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc for some tips.

sorry, rereading this I realized an example might help...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  if ($row['DURATION'] == "One Day Rental"){
    #delete the row
  }

}
```